# A function for returning part of a product or record depending on parameter and requested return type

Tags: haskell, generic-programming, scrap-your-boilerplate

I'm looking for a function, that, given the necessary return type, will return the part of a product parameter that matches that type, based purely on the structure of the type passed to the function.

For example:

```
data MyProduct = MyProduct String Int Bool

prod = MyProduct "yes" 0 False

func prod :: Boolean -- would return False
func prod :: String  -- would return "yes"
func prod :: Double  -- compiler error
```

And similarly, for the same function `func`, but a different product:

```
data AnotherProduct = AP (Maybe Int) Char

ap = AP Nothing 'C'

func ap :: Maybe Int -- would return Nothing
```

Does such a function exist? I feel this should be possible, perhaps using `Generic`. I know that this is possible in other languages, such as Scala with the Shapeless library, but I can't work out how best to approach this in Haskell.

Comment: A relevant package for this is generic-lens.

Answer (score 3):

As per @Li-yao_Xia's answer, it is possible to do this with `GHC.Generics` (which is what `generic-lens` uses behind the scenes).  The code in `generic-lens` is probably a little hard to follow, so here's how you can do it from scratch.

The way `GHC.Generics` works, it represents a particular type, such as:

```
data MyProduct = MyProduct String Int Bool deriving (Generic)
```

by means of an isomorphic type `Rep MyProduct` that looks like this:

```
> :kind! Rep MyProduct
Rep MyProduct :: * -> *
= D1
    ('MetaData "MyProduct" "GenericFetch3" "main" 'False)
    (C1
       ('MetaCons "MyProduct" 'PrefixI 'False)
       (S1
          ('MetaSel
             'Nothing 'NoSourceUnpackedness 'NoSourceStrictness 'DecidedLazy)
          (Rec0 String)
        :*: (S1
               ('MetaSel
                  'Nothing 'NoSourceUnpackedness 'NoSourceStrictness 'DecidedLazy)
               (Rec0 Int)
             :*: S1
                   ('MetaSel
                      'Nothing 'NoSourceUnpackedness 'NoSourceStrictness 'DecidedLazy)
                   (Rec0 Bool))))
```

This is admittedly a little crazy, but most of this nested type consists of metadata wrappers represented by `D1`, `C1`, and `S1` types.  If you remove those wrappers, it boils down to:

```
Rep MyProduct = Rec0 String :*: Rec0 Int :*: Rec0 Bool
```

which helps show how the representation is structured.

Anyway, to write a generic function, you create a typeclass that can process a `Rep a` using instances to handle metadata wrappers and the small set of type constructors used to represent products, sums, etc.

In our case, we're going to define a typeclass `Fetch'` that lets us fetch the first value of type `b` out of a representation `t` (i.e., so `t` will be `Rep MyProduct` or something similar):

```
class Fetch' t b where
  fetch' :: t p -> Maybe b
```

For now, we're not going to require that `t` actually contain a `b`, which is why we allow `fetch'` to return `Nothing`.

We'll need an instance to process metadata:

```
instance Fetch' t b => Fetch' (M1 i m t) b where
  fetch' (M1 x) = fetch' x
```

Since all the metadata wrappers (`D1`, `S1`, and `C1`) are actually aliases (`M1 D`, `M1 S`, `M1 C` respectively), we can handle them all with an `M1` instance that passes the `fetch'` through the wrapper.

We'll also need one to process products:

```
instance (Fetch' s b, Fetch' t b) => Fetch' (s :*: t) b where
  fetch' (s :*: t) = fetch' s <|> fetch' t
```

This will just fetch the `b` out of the left-hand side of the product or -- failing that -- out of the right-hand side.

And we'll need an instance to fetch a `b` out of a (top-level) field of the matching type (which matches the `Rec0` above, since that's just an alias for `K1 R`):

```
instance Fetch' (K1 i b) b where
  fetch' (K1 x) = Just x
```

as well as an overlapped catch-all that will handle fields of the wrong type:

```
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Fetch' (K1 i b) a where
  fetch' (K1 _) = Nothing
```

We could also optionally handle the other possible type constructors in these representations (namely, `V1`, `U1`, and `:+:`) which I've done in the complete example below.

Anyway, with those instances in place, we could write:

```
fetch1 :: (Generic t, Fetch' (Rep t) b) => t -> b
fetch1 = fromJust . fetch' . from
```

and this works fine:

```
> fetch1 prod :: String
"yes"
> fetch1 prod :: Int
0
> fetch1 prod :: Bool
False
```

but as with @luqui's answer based on `Data` generics, it doesn't catch bad fields at compile time but rather crashes at runtime:

```
> fetch1 prod :: Double
*** Exception: Maybe.fromJust: Nothing
```

To fix this, we can introduce a type family that calculates whether a data structure (or rather it's `Rep`) actually contains the needed field, like so:

```
type family Has t b where
  Has (s :*: t) b = Or (Has s b) (Has t b)
  Has (K1 i b) b = 'True
  Has (K1 i a) b = 'False
  Has (M1 i m t) b = Has t b
```

with the usual definition for the type family `Or`.  Now, we can add this as a constraint in the definition of `fetch`:

```
fetch :: ( Generic t
         , Has (Rep t) b ~ 'True
         , Fetch' (Rep t) b)
      => t -> b
fetch = fromJust . fetch' . from
```

and now we get a compile time error for bad fields:

```
> fetch prod :: String
"yes"
> fetch prod :: Double

<interactive>:83:1: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘'False’ with ‘'True’
        arising from a use of ‘fetch’
    • In the expression: fetch prod :: Double
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = fetch prod :: Double
>
```

Anyway, putting the whole thing together, and adding instances and `Has` definitions for all the constructors, we get the following version.  Note that for sum types (i.e., `(:+:)`), it only allows field types that can be found in all terms in the sum (and so are guaranteed to be present).  Unlike the `typed` function in `generic-lens`, this version allows multiple fields of the target type in a product and just picks the first one.

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

module GenericFetch where

import Control.Applicative
import Data.Maybe
import GHC.Generics

data MyProduct = MyProduct String Int Bool deriving (Generic)
prod :: MyProduct
prod = MyProduct "yes" 0 False

data AnotherProduct = AP (Maybe Int) Char deriving (Generic)
ap :: AnotherProduct
ap = AP Nothing 'C'

data ASum = A Int String | B Int Double deriving (Generic)
asum :: ASum
asum = A 10 "hello"

class Fetch' t b where
  fetch' :: t p -> Maybe b
instance Fetch' V1 b where
  fetch' _ = Nothing
instance Fetch' U1 b where
  fetch' _ = Nothing
instance (Fetch' s b, Fetch' t b) => Fetch' (s :+: t) b where
  fetch' (L1 s) = fetch' s
  fetch' (R1 t) = fetch' t
instance (Fetch' s b, Fetch' t b) => Fetch' (s :*: t) b where
  fetch' (s :*: t) = fetch' s <|> fetch' t
instance Fetch' (K1 i b) b where
  fetch' (K1 x) = Just x
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Fetch' (K1 i b) a where
  fetch' (K1 _) = Nothing
instance Fetch' t b => Fetch' (M1 i m t) b where
  fetch' (M1 x) = fetch' x

type family Has t b where
  Has V1 b = 'False
  Has U1 b = 'False
  Has (s :+: t) b = And (Has s b) (Has t b)
  Has (s :*: t) b = Or (Has s b) (Has t b)
  Has (K1 i b) b = 'True
  Has (K1 i a) b = 'False
  Has (M1 i m t) b = Has t b
type family Or a b where
  Or 'False 'False = 'False
  Or a b = 'True
type family And a b where
  And 'True 'True = 'True
  And a b = 'False

fetch :: ( Generic t
         , Has (Rep t) b ~ 'True
         , Fetch' (Rep t) b)
      => t -> b
fetch = fromJust . fetch' . from
```

giving:

```
> :l GenericFetch
> fetch prod :: Int
0
> fetch prod :: Double
...type error...
> fetch ap :: Maybe Int
Nothing
> fetch ap :: Int
...type error...
> fetch asum :: Int
10
> fetch asum :: String
... type error: no string in `B` constructor...
>
```

Comment: I didn't think of / know about working directly with the result of `Rep`. Great technique!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to get a list of all compatible fields:

```
import Data.Data
import Data.Typeable
import Data.Maybe (maybeToList)

fields :: (Data a, Typeable b) => a -> [b]
fields = gmapQr (++) [] (maybeToList . cast)
```

The product types you use should derive `Data`.  This can be done automatically with `{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}`

```
data MyProduct = MyProduct String Int Bool
    deriving (Typeable, Data)
```

See the docs for [`gmapQr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Data.html#v:gmapQr) and [`cast`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#v:cast).

The only caveat is that I can't think of a way to give a *compile-time* error when you request a field that is not present, as you requested.  We would need some sort of compile-time version of `Data.Data`. I'm not aware of any such thing, though I suspect it is possible (it would probably be a bit more of a pain though––that `deriving Data` is doing a lot of the heavy lifting for us!).

Answer (score 2):

One solution is in [generic-lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-lens). In particular, `getTyped @T :: P -> T` will access a field of type `T` in any product type `P` (that is an instance of `Generic`). Here's an example in GHCi  (for more details, see the README):

```
> :set -XDeriveGeneric -XTypeApplications
> import Data.Generics.Product
> import GHC.Generics
> data MyProduct = MyProduct String Int Bool deriving Generic
> getTyped @Int (MyProduct "Hello" 33 True)
33
> getTyped @Int (0 :: Int, "hello")
0
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done with under the Haskell 98 standard.  In general, a parametric function cannot change behavior based the concrete type that it becomes.  It must remain generic.

As a thought process as to why this might be consider the case:

```
data MpProduct a = My Product Int Int String [a]
```

What should the `func` return asked for an Int?  What about when `a` is Char?

Now, I'm not saying that some crack-shot of a programmer with a deep knowledge of GHC extensions could not make this happen, but it is not possible with the standard Hindley Milner typechecker.

Comment: I know impossibility arguments are fun, but my gut says `Generic` and `Typeable` could handle this without much trouble. (You would need the constraints of course, which are what let you escape from this argument)